# Is M_PI*2 (in Cocos2d) equal to 1 second? How?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, accelerometer

what tells us that this is in "second" ? (is `M_PI*2` equal to 1 second? how?)

```
float32 maxRevsPerSecond = 7.0;
float32 accelerationFraction = acceleration.y*6;
float32 motorSpeed = (M_PI*2) * maxRevsPerSecond * accelerationFraction;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`M_PI` is the system's definiton for the value of π (3.14159...) Thefefore, `motorSpeed` is an angular (rotational) value in [radians](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian) per second.

---

The above initial answer was only based on the variable names in the example code. Doing some net searching, I see this code is part of an example in the book *Learning Cocos2D*. In the section *Making the Cart Move with the Accelerometer* the book says:

> Since you set up **revolute** joints for the cart wheels, rotating the wheels is easy. Revolute joints have a built-in “motor” that defines how quickly the wheels rotate in radians per second.
>
> ...
>
> Think of a motor as an automatic mechanism that turns the wheels based on the motorSpeed. motorSpeed is in radians per second,...

Comment: thanks Brian, i don't really get it. What defines that this is per second? couldn't it be per "dt" for example, the time between the old frame and the new frame in the game?